# Can't install pyperclip, multiple instances of Python

Tags: python, pyperclip

I had to download the Microsoft store version of Python for BS Windows compatibility reasons- I'd been working off of the direct python download before this. Recently, I was messing with PATH stuff and messed up in a weird way. I deleted my C:\ProgramFiles(x86) PATH on accident and launched a system restore to get it back.

Things got worse from there.

When my computer relaunched, my web browsers were deleted. Unrelated, but weird.

I went back to working on PATH stuff, and solved my original WIN + R problems.

However, as soon as I launched a program with pyperclip, the module was no longer present. I've installed pip, and pyperclip using cmd but I can't import the module into IDLE or run it in my programs.

I think it has to do with the multiple versions of Python and some directory issue.

Is there any way to install pyperclip in all versions of Python present? I don't want to deal with more issues by trying to delete just one instance of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems solve themselves. I just kept messing with file locations and running `pip install pyperclip` in cmd. Buffed out.